# Working Set "Other Projects" in Eclipse Juno gone?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno, working-set

When selecting working sets as top level elements in Eclipse Indigo's project explorer, there was always a virtual working set `Other Projects`. But in Juno now, it seems like projects outside any working set are just not displayed... Is there a way to re-enable this behaviour?

**Update:**

Here's a screenshot of the `Select Working Sets...` dialog:
[image]

Comment: Pleased add a picture of your "Configure Working Sets" dialog as well..

Comment: Where is this, I can't find it...

Comment: In the navigation view, in the view menu, select "Configure Working Sets...".

Comment: Had the same problem. Try using `package explorer` instead of `project explorer`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found this, I have look this too.

Just change Perspective 'Java EE' to 'Java'

**Window -> Open Perspective -> Java**

Comment: Worked! But... Why not in the Java EE perspective? o.O

Comment: I don't know why, maybe a Bug?

Comment: There is the Package Explorer which has 'Other Projects' and there is the (new?) Navigator which does not.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach This is a bug. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=268838

Answer (score 3):

This is not linked to the perspective but rather to the view.

The project explorer view doesn't have an **"Other Projects"** Working set.

Instead, if you want access to this functionality, you should use the **"Package Explorer"** View.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Not related with the perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You can decide on this yourself...

In the navigation view, in the view menu, select "Configure Working Sets...".

In the shown dialog (see below), you can select whether to add the "Other Projects" working set or not...

[image: Configure Working Sets Dialog]

Comment: I've seen this menu as well, but `Other Projects` does not appear there... Which version are you using? (Btw, I'll update my question with a screen shot)